# CSOM get subsites times out

Tags: csom, sub-site

I'm trying to fetch all subsites (just those at the root level, not sub-subsites, etc.). But, I suspect due to volume (4,000+ subsites), the following times out.

```
clientContext.Load(
    clientContext.Web.Webs,
    w => w.Include(s => s.Url),
    w => w.Include(s => s.RoleAssignments));
await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

I've tried increasing the timeout by setting `clientContext.RequestTimeout = 600000;`, but then instead of timing out, the query eventually results in error: `The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.`

Is there some way I can paginate the results, or another way I can fetch a list of subsites that won't result in a timeout?

Comment: try with clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the `RequestTimeout` property on the context can help, but it can only go so far before you come up against HTTP 503 errors. I still don't know how to page results, but something that *significantly* improves performance is to greatly limit the number of fields included in the result, like:

```
projectContext.Load(
    project.Web.Webs,
    w => w.Include(s => s.Url));
await _pwaContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

Using this method, I retrieved 4,300 projects in less than a second, whereas **not** specifying the limited set of properties by using `Include(..)` would usually fail.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this [extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontextextensions.executequeryretry?view=sharepointpnpcoreonline-2.18.1709.0)?

You can install it via Nuget 
`Install-Package SharePointPnPCoreOnline -Version 3.8.1904`

It extends the `ClientContext` object and

> Executes the current set of data retrieval queries and method invocations and retries it if needed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/99297)

Comment: Updated my anwser